# How do I launch a certain project using SWTBot

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, swtbot

Not every plugin can be tested without project. For example, I want to test CDT-Plug-in, therefore I need to import a C-project. But there is no such point in Run Configuration and when I'm trying to record importing actions via SWT Plug-in Test recorder SWTBot can't replay them afterwards. Google is silent on this topic. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

A nice way to do this is using the eclipse recource model
Have a look at the package

```
org.eclipse.core.resources
```

Here is a method, that creates a new project in the workspace

```
private IProject getNewOpenProject(IWorkspace wks, String name)
        throws CoreException {
    System.out.print("Creating project " + name + "...");
    IProjectDescription prj1ProjectDescription = wks
            .newProjectDescription(name);
    IProject prj = wks.getRoot().getProject(name);
    prj.create(prj1ProjectDescription, null);
    prj.open(null);
    System.out.println("    [OK]");
    return prj;
}
```

This method will import your content into the eclipse project

```
private void importDirIntoProject(File srcPath, IProject prj,
        IOverwriteQuery overwriteQuery) throws InvocationTargetException,
        InterruptedException {
    ImportOperation op = new ImportOperation(prj.getFullPath(), srcPath,
            FileSystemStructureProvider.INSTANCE, overwriteQuery);
    op.setCreateContainerStructure(false);
    op.run(new NullProgressMonitor());
}
```

This approach uses native eclipse mechanisms. I think this is better than using the inconvenient way over SWTBot.

Answer (score 0):

It's the responsibility of your test to create the necessary resources in its setup method, and clean them after. It's not something to configure in the Run Configuration, but to code in your test.

You can either use SWTBot to import/create a C project, or use the project APIs suggested by beanie.